# If statement on pseudo Vlookup Function in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I made the following function in apps script to recreate a vlookup that is done in google sheets and insert the results into a new cell:

```
function doLookUP() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const wsCombine = ss.getSheetByName('Results Data');
  const wsAlliance = ss.getSheetByName('VlookUp Data');
  const Avals = wsCombine.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  const Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;

  const imageData = wsAlliance.getRange(2,1,wsAlliance.getLastRow()-1,2).getValues()
  const searchValues = wsCombine.getRange(2,4,wsCombine.getLastRow()).getValues()

  const matchingImage = searchValues.map(searchRow => {
    searchRow[0]
    const matchRow = imageData.find(r => r[2] == searchRow[0])
    return match = matchRow ? [matchRow[2]] : [" "]
  })


wsCombine.getRange(2,5,Alast,1).setValues(matchingImage)
  

}
```

The Data in the sheets looks like this:

Results Data:

| header1 | ID | header2 | numericID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| testData | id12 | testdata | 2131 |
| testData | id11 | testdata | 78954 |
| testData | id13 | testdata | 8985 |
| testData | id10 | testdata | 45321 |

VlookUp Data

| ID Number | CT |
| --- | --- |
| id12 | CR |
| 78954 | TK |
| id13 | HK |
| 45321 | US |

At the moment the code is doing the look up in one column (ID) and returning values, however I would like to do the same only that if the look up bring data as blank to look into the the other columns that has data (numericID) and to bring results like this:

| header1 | ID | header2 | numericID | CT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| testData | id12 | testdata | 2131 | CR |
| testData | id11 | testdata | 78954 | TK |
| testData | id13 | testdata | 8985 | HK |
| testData | id10 | testdata | 45321 | US |

EDIT: I've made a change to the table where the Result data is as I can't make the column into a single array and do a lookup based on that as there may be data on the column instead of blank, however on the VlookUp Data table there's only one ID.

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how to compare a value with more than one column value.

Notice that Array.some() is like break when the condition is met.

I did not address if the value is not found in the lookup table.

**Code.gs**

```
function doLookUp() {
  try {
    let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let wsCombine = ss.getSheetByName('Results Data');
    let wsAlliance = ss.getSheetByName('VlookUp Data');
    let imageData = wsAlliance.getRange(2,1,wsAlliance.getLastRow()-1,2).getValues();
    let searchValues = wsCombine.getDataRange().getValues();
    searchValues.shift(); // remove headers
    let find = [["CT"]];
    searchValues.map( (row,index) => {
        find.push(["not found"]);  //  added
        imageData.some( image => { 
            if( ( row[1] === image[0] ) || ( row[2] === image[0] ) ) {
              find[index+1] = [image[1]];  //  updated
              return true;
            }
            return false;
          }
        );
      }
    );
    console.log(find);
    wsCombine.getRange(1,5,find.length,1).setValues(find);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Execution log**

```
10:36:33 AM Notice  Execution started
10:36:35 AM Info    [ [ 'CT' ], [ 'CR' ], [ 'TK' ], [ 'HK' ], [ 'US' ] ]
10:36:35 AM Notice  Execution completed
```

**Reference**

- [Array.shift()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_shift.asp)
- [Array.map()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)
- [Array.some()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_some.asp)
- [Array.push()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)

Comment: so the code works, but the first time that I ran it the file has 10k lines and now the file has 11 k lines, and it's giving me an error that the file needs to be 10k to execute? Any idea on this? the error goes like this:  The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 10231 but the range has 11026.

Comment: Perhaps you have some extraneous data at the end of your sheet introducing blank rows?  I tested it for the data you've shown.  In my script I'm using find.length as the number of rows so it matches the length of the array find.  Your error message implies that you have done something different.  If my script doesn't find a value in the lookup table it doesn't handle this error.  I've made some changes to the script to address this.

Comment: The only change I did was to change the sheet names and that's it, what I find interesting is that no there's no blank rows as the data changed due to more lines been added to the Results Data, my question is: why is getting the length of the old data before the update?

Comment: If you'll notice, I use `wsCombine.getDataRange()` which sets the number of rows of data.  I then use `searchValues.map( )` which will create the array `find` the same size as the data.  I then put `find` in column 5 so it should be the same size as the original data array.

Comment: I even introduced a row that does not have an Id to test for error and my script still works.  I believe there is something different about your data then you posted.